# Replacing a div id and changing css height (with overflow-y: "scroll") breaks javascript lazy load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, lazy-loading

I'm doing 2 changes on a div with jQuery:

```
if (jQuery("#geodir-wrapper-content").length > 0){
        document.getElementById("geodir-wrapper-content").id = 'geodir_content';
}
```

as well as:

```
jQuery("#geodir_content").css({
        height: "calc(100vh - "+contentHeight+"px)", 
        'overflow-y': "scroll",
        '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': "touch"
});
```

The result is exactly what I want: the right shape and the right CSS classes are applied to the div.

The content within this div has images loading with lazy load javascript. The first images load fine, but when scrolling *inside* this div the new images don't load. They only load when the window gets resized or if there is a possibility so scroll on the main page (which I don't have on my final design).

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7m9hdaf/) with the complete setup. Note that I can't modify the lazy load javascript as it's part of a plugin, so I'd like to find a workaround in my own code.

Comment: the last 2 pictures in the fiddle are loading for me, just that they take a few seconds to load.

Comment: Not if the bottom right window is small enough to display only the first or first and second. Just tried again in a different browser. If you "only" scroll inside the frame containing text and images, they never load.